# Firestore unwanted saving of repeated entries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to store locations nearby me for a test. I ran the following code:

```
var macro_query = db.collection("cafes");
    macro_query = macro_query.where("name", "==", place.name); // check whether name exists
    console.log("Checking final query: ", macro_query); // check whether it exists
    macro_query.get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log(querySnapshot.empty); // returns true if empty, returns false if place.name is already in database

        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          db.collection("cafes").add({ // store it since it doesnt exist
            name: place.name,
          });
          console.log("Added into database: ", place.name);
        } else {
          console.log("Location already in database");
        }
      });
```

The logic of the code is basically to check the database if `place.name` already exist. If it does, the script does nothing, otherwise the place should be added to the database.

The code works fine after a couple of tests, to make sure that it never adds the same location twice. But after running it many many times, i noticed that in my firestore there could be more than 2 unique keys with the same location (meaning, 3 locations with the exact same name)

Is my code failing somewhere and I'm not matching it correctly?

Side note, I'm wondering if this is because of my security rules?

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with security rules.

Your code has a race condition.  Since there is some brief period of time between the query and the update, that means you could end up with multiple concurrent queries each adding a store with the same name.  Unfortunately, for Firestore web and mobile clients, there is no way to make this sort of query atomic in order to avoid the race condition.  Firestore transactions won't help you here, since you can't do a query inside of a transaction.

If you want to atomically check-and-set, the thing to check **must** the document ID, not a field in the document.  If you're looking for a specific document by ID, you can then use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to only create the document if it doesn't already exist.  This also implies either one of two things:

1. Your store names are also valid document IDs
2. Or you have a dedicated collection for storing encoded store names as document IDs, with parallel documents in another collection that actually contain the store data.

If you choose #2, you are in for quite a bit of work to make that happen smoothly.

Comment: Very interesting. I understand, may I ask if it would be possible to implement a testAndSet(lock) for the critical section (the query and update) to ensure that only one query and update runs at one time?

Comment: No, Firestore is designed to handle up to a million concurrent connections - there is absolutely no query serialization.  It would get misused and become massively bad.

Comment: Right, so the easiest way would to use the transaction on my store names? Could you elaborate on 1. ?

Comment: The documentation I linked to will show you how to do a transaction.